# How to import MATLAB trained CNN network to LabVIEW

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, labview

I have a few matlab trained deep learning networks to classify images, and I want to use them in the LabVIEW. And I want to preload the networks at the very beginning, instead of loading the networks between codes. But the MATLAB node in LabView cannot output a network.

I have tried to use the Deep Learning Module in LabView, but the supported tensorflow version is too low for my network to work. I read that DataPlugin for MATLAB could work, but I didn't find any example of how it works.

Comment: What's the version of TensorFlow in LabView?

Comment: Did you try exporting the network to the ONNX format?

Comment: I believe the deep learning package in LabVIEW supports TF 1.14. And I will look into the ONNX format. Thank you for being so helpful.